# CSS Grid Specify First Column and set Fractional Unit For Unknown Remaining

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to learn the CSS grid, but having trouble with what seems like it should be a basic repeat. Consider the following; I have 3 div elements in a header tag. I want the first div to be at least 450px and the remaining div elements (which could be 2, 3 or 4) to all be equal parts of the remaining space.

I assumed the following would work, but it seems it's not as straightforward as I thought. What am I missing?

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(450px, 1fr) repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <p>450px</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>1fr</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>1fr</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `auto-fit` instead of `auto-fill`:

[`auto-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat())

*Behaves the same as auto-fill, except that after placing the grid items any empty repeated tracks are collapsed. An empty track is one with no in-flow grid items placed into or spanning across it. (This can result in all tracks being collapsed, if they’re all empty.)*

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(450px, 1fr) repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <p>450px</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>1fr</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>1fr</p>
  </div>
</header>
<header>
  <div>
    <p>450px</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>1fr</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>1fr</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>1fr</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great, but it should probably be noted you also need the minmax with a 0 minimum when with out that I was getting the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You need a column flow for this:

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow:column; /* column flow */
  grid-template-columns: minmax(450px, 1fr); /* first column */
  grid-auto-columns:1fr; /* all remaining equal width */
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <p>450px</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>1fr</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>1fr</p>
  </div>
</header>

<header>
  <div>
    <p>450px</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>1fr</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>1fr</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>1fr</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: This actually seems to work better than the other method using the repeat and should probably be the correct answer. However I would expect the columns to wrap to rows at 450 and it seemed like it did not. Is there an additional property for this?

Comment: @user10012 you cannot have a wrap configuration with CSS grid like this, you will need flexbox for that